# How to make an alias permanent?

Tags: shell, alias

I have created an alias:

```
alias shh='sqlplus hfdora/hfdora@hfd1"
```

After creating this alias I was able to enter my database only by typing `shh`.

But after closing my shell, I wasn't able to find the alias next time. Even after typing only `alias`, `shh` was not showing in the list.

Is there any file to make an alias permanent so that it will not be erased?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `ksh`:

```
printf "%s\n" "alias shh='sqlplus hfdora/hfdora@hfd1" >> ~/.kshrc
source ~/.kshrc
```

For `bash`:

```
printf "%s\n" "alias shh='sqlplus hfdora/hfdora@hfd1" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

For `zsh`:

```
printf "%s\n" "alias shh='sqlplus hfdora/hfdora@hfd1" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

---

Use `source` for the instant effect

---

And as [@glennjackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) said:

> A note to readers: `~/.kshrc` is for `ksh93`. For `ksh88`, either put
>   your aliases in `~/.profile`, or use `~/.kshrc` but add this to your
>   `~/.profile`:
>
> ```
> export ENV=$HOME/.kshrc
> ```

Comment: I am using .kshrc.... so it will be in ~/.kshrc?

Comment: @Nainita Yes, do that =)

Comment: What are those `printf` statements supposed to do? They're not updating the *rc file

Comment: @glennjackman sorry, I forgot `>>` =\

Comment: A note to readers: `~/.kshrc` is for ksh93. For ksh88, either put your aliases in `~/.profile`, or use ~/.kshrc but add this to your ~/.profile: `export ENV=$HOME/.kshrc`

Answer (score 2):

put your alias inside your `~/.bash_aliases` file.

If it's not present create one and call it from `~/.bashrc`

OR you can directly put it inside your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I am using .kshrc

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your `.bashrc` file. Then it will be an alias in every instance of Bash shell you open.

Answer (score 0):

## To Add a Temporary Alias:

1. Goto Terminal (I'm using git bash for windows).
2. Type `$ alias gpuom='git push origin master'`
3. To See a List of All the aliases type `$ alias` hit Enter.

## To Add a Permanent Alias:

1. Goto Terminal (I'm using git bash for windows).
2. Type `$ vim ~/.bashrc` and hit Enter (I'm guessing you are familiar with vim).
3. Add your new aliases (For reference look at the snippet below).

   ```
   #My custom aliases  
   alias gpuom='git push origin master' 
   alias gplom='git pull origin master'
   ```
4. Save and Exit (Press Esc then type :wq).
5. To See a List of All the aliases type `alias` hit Enter.